# SpringMVC and FreeMarker

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

Can anyone please show me hello world example for springmavc with freemarker.
I googled number of sites even freemarker site but did not find any useful that shows how to use freemarker with springmvc.
So please can any one write a hello world type simple program to show how to use freemarker with springmvc or suggest me some website where I can find psringmvc and freemarker configurations from scratch.

I know it is too basic to ask but hope you me.

Thanks

Comment: Try this : http://www.earldouglas.com/a-self-contained-runnable-web-application. Hope it helps.

Comment: Look at this: http://code.google.com/p/petclinicplus/

Comment: The simplest, well written example I could find using standard Spring MVC approaches is mentioned in this StackOverflow answer. I'd just link to the source, but there's some info in the post as well that you should read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6963416/26510

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the Spring documentation for both [Velocity and Freemarker](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-velocity). You need to set-up a FreeMarkerConfigurer bean and a FreeMarkerViewResolver, and that's about it.

```
<!-- freemarker config -->
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
  <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/"/>
</bean>

<!-- 

  View resolvers can also be configured with ResourceBundles or XML files. If you need
  different view resolving based on Locale, you have to use the resource bundle resolver.

-->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
  <property name="cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="prefix" value=""/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
</bean>
```